# Problem configuring mosquitto v2.0.15 to listen on interface (by interface name)

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, mosquitto

I'm running Mosquitto 2.0.15 on ubuntu 20.04

and I want to configure to listen on a specific interface,
but I don't want to hardcode the interface address

the interface I want to listen on is:

```
enp3s0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), 00:E2:69:3D:CA:C2, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.2.115/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.2.0/24
        inet6 fe80::9490:96c4:9f56:d81c/64
        route6 fe80::/64
```

Can anybody please help me?

Thanks,
Nadav

I run the mosquitto like this:

`sudo mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf`

If I configure the mosquitto like this:

```
listener  8882 192.168.2.115
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true
```

it works OK,

I tried this:

```
listener  8882
bind_interface enp3s0
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true
```

but I get error:

```
2022/11/30 10:35:12: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8882.
2022/11/30 10:35:12: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8882.
2022/11/30 10:35:12: Error: Invalid argument
```

I tried this:

```
listener  8882
bind_interface Wired connection 1
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true
```

and I get:

```
2022/11/30 10:35:55: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8882.
2022/11/30 10:35:55: Warning: Interface Wired connection 1 does not support IPv4 configuration.
2022/11/30 10:35:55: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8882.
2022/11/30 10:35:55: Warning: Interface Wired connection 1 does not support IPv6 configuration.
```

I even tried (there is NO eth0 interface):

```
listener  8882
bind_interface XXXX
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true
```

and I get:

```
2022/11/30 10:37:29: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8882.
2022/11/30 10:37:29: Warning: Interface XXXX does not support IPv4 configuration.
2022/11/30 10:37:29: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8882.
2022/11/30 10:37:29: Warning: Interface XXXX does not support IPv6 configuration.
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
listener  8882
bind_interface enp3s0
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true
```

And works as expected (with a suitable changed device name to match my wifi adapter) on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine with mosquitto 2.0.15.

Do you have more in your config file that the syntax error could be releated to?

Comment: I just created a config file that contains only these lines.
If I comment out the bind_interface line it works OK,
If it's uncommented, I get the Invalid argument error.

Comment: The fact that if I put in an invalid interface name, I get a different error,
makes me think that it's NOT a syntax error,
but some error that happens when the mosquitto tries to configure the tcp listener on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with ipv6

strace shows

```
bind(5, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(8882), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::9490:96c4:9f56:d81c", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "1669878630: Error: Invalid argum"..., 361669878630: Error: Invalid argument
)
```

adding

```
socket_domain ipv4
```

to the config file solves the problem

mosquitto documentation does not say that bind_interface only works on ipv4

Comment: `bind_interface` should work just fine with IPv6. The test I ran was on a machine with full IPv6 enabled (included fully routed publich IPv6 addresses). If you think you have found a bug I suggest you raise it with the project [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues)